# Savon ruby gem getting Savon::SOAPFault on request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

My code is pretty simple:

```
client = Savon.client(wsdl: wsdl_url, follow_redirects: true)
response = client.call(:obtener_cotizacion, message: { fecha: '2022-08-02' })
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        8: from bin/console:8:in `<main>'
        7: from (irb):82
        6: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/client.rb:37:in `call'
        5: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:65:in `call'
        4: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:76:in `create_response'
        3: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/operation.rb:76:in `new'
        2: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/response.rb:20:in `initialize'
        1: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/savon-2.13.0/lib/savon/response.rb:132:in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!'
Savon::SOAPFault ((S:Client) Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Trying to declare prefix 'xmlns' (illegal as per NS 1.1 #4))
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,585]
```

I have no idea what that means, I have never declared any prefix in my other integrations.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: something similar happened to me. I opened an issue https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/986

Answer (score 0):

The error seams to be introduced in this commit: https://github.com/savonrb/savon/commit/045082c9d18ed538da072b4a4681e79c16dac17b

Have you tried downgrading Savonrb to version 2.12.1?

Comment: I have the same error too using the version 2.13.0 so I decided to downgrade to 2.12.1.

Comment: I am using version 2.13 and I was using 2.12.1. But I don't know if this code works on version 2.12.1 really, I just tested it on 2.13

Comment: @alebian let us know if downgrading works for you. It did for me.